# Adding column that displays count of record under same group gridview yii2

Tags: php, mysql, gridview, yii2

I am trying to count the record with the same group in a table. I know this is attainable easily with a query and yes I already done it but I am thinking of the proper way to place the count on main models and search models.

The database looks like this:

```
Device
----------------------------
id    name          group_id
1    Phone Sony        2
2    Computer          1
3    Printer           1
4    Phone LG          1


Group
----------------------------
id    name          
1    Home
2    Office
```

OUTPUT TABLE:

```
Group Name   Device Count
  Home           1
  Office         3
```

I have done this by doing a query on the controller.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM  `hosts` 
WHERE group_id = *~DESIRED NUMBER HERE~*
```

I am looking for a better approach. I am new to SQL and I think `joining tables` is the proper way to do this but I am still not very sure.

Under `GroupSearch` model I will add this:

```
$dataProvider->setSort(['attributes' => [
            'devicecount' => [
                 'asc' => [ 'devicecount' => SORT_ASC ],
                 'desc' => [ 'devicecount' => SORT_DESC ],
            ],
        ]
 ]);
```

Since `devicecount` is not available in the tables it will show an error. Where should I put the counting of the same store_id? Under `Device` model or under `Group` model? How will I be able to sort them also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of handling this kind of situations in [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields).

Example of model:

```
class Group extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $devicesCount;

    // ...

    public function getDevices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Device::className(), ['group_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Example of query:

```
$customers = Group::find()
    ->select([
        '{{group}}.*', // select all customer fields
        'COUNT({{device}}.id) AS ordersCount' // calculate orders count
    ])
    ->joinWith('devices') // ensure table junction
    ->groupBy('{{group}}.id') // group the result to ensure aggregation function works
    ->all();
```

where `{{group}}` and `{{device}}` - table names for groups and devices accordingly, or you can use `Group::tableName()` and `Device::tableName()` for better code maintaining.

Then because you added count as model property, you will be able to sort results by this column.

Comment: Thanks! I am really sorry but I am having a hard time understanding your answer. What is your table like? and where did you place your query?

Comment: How can I add also `->where (*some condition*)` ?

Comment: @Gibs This example is taken from the docs. Correct it according to your conditions. You can add it as `->andWhere()`  before `->all()` call.

Comment: @Gibs I updated answer according to your situation for better undestanding. Hope this helps.